# Conflict with bootstrap.css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a search dropdown that will need to put some keywords and that will allow the user to select the date range he wants. But since I added this line:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Now everything is okay except the fact that the user has a white text over a white input field.

I'm thinking about two solutions,

1. Can I choose which division will the imported script affect or not? If so, how?
2. Not really wanted solution: change the color of the field input in another color than white?

```html
<div id="advancedResearchContent" class="searchnav w3-theme-d5" style="display:none">
  <span style="position:absolute; left:35%; width:200px; top:100px;">Keywords</span><br><input type="text" id="keyword" style="position:absolute; left:42%; width:200px; top:100px;"></input>
  <span style="position:absolute; left:49%; width:200px; top:180px;">From date</span><br>
  <!--         <input type="text" id="dateBegin" style="position:absolute; left:57%; width:200px; top:180px;"></input> -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <!-- style="width:20px" -->
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' style="position:absolute; left:57%; width:220px; top:180px;">
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span style="position:absolute; left:75%; width:200px; top:180px;">To date</span><br>
  <!--         <input type="text" id="dateEnd" style="position:absolute; left:80%; width:200px; top:180px;"></input> -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2' style="position:absolute; left:80%; width:220px; top:180px;">
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>


  <span style="position:absolute; left:50%; width:200px; top:280px;">Author</span><br><input type="text" id="author" style="position:absolute; left:57%; width:200px; top:280px;"></input>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="popUpYes" style="border-radius: 5px; position: absolute; top: 280px; left:80%; width: 200px; height:40px;"></input>
  <div id="myDIV" class="header" style="background-color: #1f2c47; height:80px;  width: 510px; margin-left:7%;">
    <h4 style="margin:0px">Primary tag</h4>


    <select id="primarytag">
      <!--   <select id="primarytag"> -->
      <option selected disabled>Select primarytag:</option>
      <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
      <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
      <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
      <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
      <option value="Philosophy">Philosophy</option>
      <option value="History">History</option>
      <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
    </select>

    <!--             <input type="text" id="myInput1" placeholder="" style="z-index:1"></input> -->
    <span onclick="newElement1()" class="addBtn" style="border-radius: 0px; height:30px">Add</span>
  </div>
  <ul id="myUL1" style="width: 510px; margin-left:7%;">
  </ul>
  <br><br>
  <div id="myDIV" class="header" style="background-color: #263659; height:80px;  width: 510px; margin-left:7%;">
    <h4 style="margin:0px">Secondary tags</h4>
    <select id="secondarytag">
      <option selected disabled>Select secondarytag:</option>
      <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
      <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
      <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
      <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
      <option value="Philosophy">Philosophy</option>
      <option value="History">History</option>
      <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: where is the rest of your code??

Comment: @mlegg Here you go, sorry,

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your need, but why wouldn't you just use css to change the text color of your input (not the background)?